# FontAwesome 5 javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-brands-400.eot]}]

Tags: css, primefaces, el, font-awesome-5

I am new to CSS & Font awesome world, I got an issue while updating my Font Awesome from 4.4.0 to 5.0.10 in primfaces atlas theme,

here is the exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <ILLEGAL_CHARACTER> "\' "" at line 1, column 12.
Was expecting one of:
    "{" ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "(" ...
    "[" ...
    "!" ...
    "not" ...
    "empty" ...
    "-" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "(" ...

    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.generateParseException(ELParser.java:3090)
```

And my

> fa fa icons working fine, but not the new ones like FAB,FAR

[image]

I have added files which I downloaded from fontAwesome and replaced with old one,
And Edited the font-awesome.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-brands-400.eot]}");
  src: url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-brands-400.eot]}?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2]}") format("woff2"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-brands-400.woff]}") format("woff"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf]}") format("truetype"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-brands-400.svg]}#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

.fab {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands'; }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-regular-400.eot]}");
  src: url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-regular-400.eot]}?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2]}") format("woff2"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-regular-400.woff]}") format("woff"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf]}") format("truetype"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-regular-400.svg]}#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

.far {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 400; }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-solid-900.eot]}");
  src: url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-solid-900.eot]}?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2]}") format("woff2"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-solid-900.woff]}") format("woff"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf]}") format("truetype"), url("#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-solid-900.svg]}#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

.fa,
.fas {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900; }
```

please help on this

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? What did you update and how?

Comment: @Kukeltje I updated  my code like how I have done this

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be completely correct. In ***EACH*** of the

```
#{resource['atlas-layout:fonts/fa-brands-400.eot]}
```

You have a single 'open' quote after the [ but not a 'closing' one before the ]. Easy to find when you compare with the [original PrimeFaces ones](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fa/font-awesome.css).